# FFmpeg crop (cut out) a view direction from 360° video sphere

Tags: ffmpeg, 360video

I have a 360×180° equirectangular video.

I want to cut out a part of it, to make it a “normal” video using FFmpeg.

Is there something like this? For example, I have a direction vector as a parameter for the region to cut out (e.g. Vector(0, 0, 1) would cut out the sky)

Comment: There is currently native filter in the works which would allow this.

Comment: that's good to hear. I had this challenge recently, and ended up using a 3D animation package. I made a sphere, used the video as the surface colour and filmed it with the virtual camera. Was faster and better quality than After Effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this filter:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360

See section "flat" and the second example to convert any 360 footage to a flat view.